# Facebook, Twitter and Gmail Integration to share links from my Android Application

Tags: android, twitter, facebook-android-sdk

I have successfully posted the page( share the links) to facebook from my android app using Facebook API. But facing lots of problems using Twitter API to do the same. Can you please suggest me how to overcome this problem. Because I have found one API integrated for all social networking sites, but it is used to share only the status(not as per my requirement).
Also how to do it for Gmail???

Comment: What is your question exactly? You want a solution for twitter or for gmail? or for both?

Comment: Both....but specially for twitter....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had same problem and i found this tutorial really helpful, please check this:

http://blog.doityourselfandroid.com/2011/02/13/guide-to-integrating-twitter-android-application/

```
public static void sendTweet(SharedPreferences prefs,String msg) throws Exception {
    String token = prefs.getString(OAuth.OAUTH_TOKEN, "");
    String secret = prefs.getString(OAuth.OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET, "");

    AccessToken a = new AccessToken(token,secret);
    Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
    twitter.setOAuthConsumer(Constants.CONSUMER_KEY, Constants.CONSUMER_SECRET);
    twitter.setOAuthAccessToken(a);
    twitter.updateStatus(msg);
}
```

Comment: if you got what you wanted so please also tick on useful

Comment: I am not sure but i guess to integrate with gmail you should use this code:  startActivity(Intent.createChooser(messageIntent, "Send email via:"));  on button click

Comment: Thanx Rakesh....but the problem I was facing in Twitter was the callback url part. After posting the link, it was not returning to my activity(from where I am sharing).Can you please guide me in that part